# LightSwitch : Attach to Online Data Source

Tags: sql-server-express, visual-studio-lightswitch

Using Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch Beta 2
How to Attach to external Data Source that could be found on my Host ?
Example :
Host : www.xxxxx.com
Database : www.xxxxx.com/Source.mdf
How can I point SQL Server to there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer on the right, right-click Data Sources and choose "Add Data Source...". Then choose Database and Microsoft SQL Server.